# HTTP to HTTPS redirect without showing index.php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have my site as HTTPS "https://website.com", so I added a htaccess file to redirect to https when I access the website through HTTP.

Here's the code that I got from SO.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

When I access http://website.com, it redirects to https://www.website.com which is correct. But when I accessed http://www.website.com, it redirects to https://www.website.com/index.php

There's an `index.php` in the url which I do not like. Are there any possible solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your code like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

You don't need multiple `RewriteEngine On` lines and keep redirect rule before internal rewrote rule as shown.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing.